# R: Web scraping from job portal

Tags: r, rvest

I am out of ideas trying to scrape data from a job portal.
Basic rvest plus xml2 package usage does not bring me to my goal to extract job title, company, location, release date as well as lower and upper salary bound.

The primitive beginnings of my coding below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
Data <- read_html("https://gehaltsreporter.de/stellenangebote-jobs/?q=Immobilienkaufmann")
```

Using the Selectorgadget tool, which e.g. identifies the job title (among others “Immobilienkaufmann”) as “.job-title”, does not work within the usual coding manner like

```
Data %>% html_nodes(“.job-title”) %>% html_text2()
```

Taking the other alternative of copying the Selectorgadget XPath CSS selector does not lead me to extracting the relevant data into R either.
Anyone who can help out?

Best,
Christoph

Answer (score 1):

Below a possible solution with `Rselenium`

In this way you are able to scrape all 72 pages.

```
install.packages('RSelenium') 
library(RSelenium)
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = FALSE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://gehaltsreporter.de/stellenangebote-jobs/?q=Immobilienkaufmann")
    all_data<-list()
    for(j in 1:72) {
      for(i in 1:14) {
        x<-remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = paste0('//*[@id="results"]/ul/li[',14,']'))
        x <- x$getElementText() 
        x <- gsub('\n', ' ', x)
        all_data[i]<-x
      }
      remDr$navigate(paste0("https://gehaltsreporter.de/stellenangebote-jobs/?q=Immobilienkaufmann&pg=",j))
      Sys.sleep(2)
      }
print(all_data)

[[1]]
[1] "Kundenberater:in für Kabel-TV und Internet-Lösungen Vodafone Deutschland GmbH Peine (DE) 03.10.2021 36.184 € - 49.284 € schätzt Gehaltsreporter.de"

[[2]]
[1] "Kundenberater:in für Kabel-TV und Internet-Lösungen Vodafone Deutschland GmbH Peine (DE) 03.10.2021 36.184 € - 49.284 € schätzt Gehaltsreporter.de"

[[3]]
[1] "Kundenberater:in für Kabel-TV und Internet-Lösungen Vodafone Deutschland GmbH Peine (DE) 03.10.2021 36.184 € - 49.284 € schätzt Gehaltsreporter.de"

[[4]]
[1] "Kundenberater:in für Kabel-TV und Internet-Lösungen Vodafone Deutschland GmbH Peine (DE) 03.10.2021 36.184 € - 49.284 € schätzt Gehaltsreporter.de"

....
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
I learned that Java as well as rJava were missing so I installed them. Next remark from R running the code was:
""C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local/binman/binman_seleniumserver app directory not found"
The only solution that I found so far was installing Docker to make the procedure work, increasing the complexity. Is there any chance to circumvent this?
Best
Christoph

Comment: It not necessary to use the docker for RSelenium. I have a couple of questions: 

1) Did you install all dependency for Rselenium packages?
2) Did you restart the pc after the Java installation?

Comment: Thank you again for answering back.
I installed JAVA 64-bit (in line with my OS), wdman package (although I had the impression that would not surely be necessary) as well as the latest selenium server standalone files (http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0/   version 4.0.0. alpha 1 and 2).
Afterwards PC restarted, selenium server files opened, R packages loaded (rJava, wdman, RSelenium) and your code run.
Unfortunately, there is still the issue from before: "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local/binman/binman_seleniumserver app directory not found"